# Problems with JS which makes hamburger animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, hamburger-menu

I wrote this piece of JS code which changes the class of the `hamburger menu` div, on most of the browsers it works but on some older it doesn't (it doesn't change the class and it doesn't give me any errors in the console).

JS code:

```js
var hamburger = document.querySelector("#hamburger"); // hamburger menu
var mtMenu = document.querySelector(".m-t-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (hamburger.classList == "close") {
        hamburger.classList = "open";
        mtMenu.style.display = "block";
    } else if(hamburger.classList == "open") {
        hamburger.classList = "close";
        mtMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Is there something wrong or is there a better way to write it without jQuery?

Comment: Please note classList is an list, and not a string. Use the addd and remove options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Thanks I change it in .className and it works

Answer (score 0):

Instead try using the method `contains`, which returns a boolean value (i.e. true or false).

```
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (hamburger.classList.contains('close'){
    hamburger.className  = 'open'
    mtMenu.style.display = 'block'
  } else if (hamburger.classList.contains('open')){
    hamburger.className  = 'close'
    mtMenu.style.display = 'none'
  }
})
```

The contains method might not be available in older browsers, however; I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it using .className instead of .classList and it works

Comment: @brenno_pellegrini I would still use the `contains` method as opposed to the comparisons you were or are using. If you found this answer useful it wouldn't hurt to up vote it <3